# import webkit fails with an ImportError

Tags: python, webkit

When I `import webkit` on Ubuntu 10.04 I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import webkit
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/webkit/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import webkit
ImportError: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/webkit/webkit.so: undefined symbol: webkit_web_frame_get_global_context
```

I think all the packages I need are installed. Does anyone have an idea of why this is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/webkit/webkit.so` is probably linked against an older version of libwebkit. In that case you'll need to install the correct versions of both software packages.

Comment: Yeah, I can affirm that. Here the project page URL: http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/